# How to have variable text in a label in tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter, label

I want the label to have one character of the text, then two, then three, then four etc. 
I understand I need to use StringVar and/or the textvariable parameter in Label.
I've tried using StringVar() as you can see. I also tried textvariable (with and without using .get()) and just text with .get(). In all cases the text either doesn't appear or appears instantly rather than in stagnation.
Here is my code:

```
class gui:
 def __init__(self, master):
     self.master = master
     master.title("VisualNovelPrototype")

     self.str = StringVar()
     self.str.set("Welcome to the game")
     self.label = Label(master, text=self.str.get())
     self.label.grid(row=0,column=1)

     self.button0 = Button(master, text="yes", command=self.start)
     self.button0.grid(row=1,column=1)

     self.button1 = Button(master, text="no", command=master.quit)
     self.button1.grid(row=2,column=1)

 def label_change(self, text):
     str = self.str
     store = ""
     for index in range(len(text)):
         store += text[index]
         str.set(store)
         time.sleep(0.08)
         self.label.config(text=self.str.get())

 def button_change(self, master, text0="", command0="", text1="", command1=""):
     self.button0.config(text=text0, command=command0)
     self.button1.config(text=text1, command=command1)

 def start(self):
     self.label_change("Its a cold night. A storm rages outside. You hear a knock at the door.")
```

Comment: It is better if you include how you use the class. Probably calling `self.label.update_idletasks()` or `self.label.update()` within the loop will work. BTW you do not need the `StringVar`, `self.label.config(text=store)` is enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think its better to use label.config(text="TEXT") during iteration as I did it in my code.
I would to advise to use more self.variables to connect them to each functions.

Here's the code:

```
from tkinter import *
import time
class gui:
 def __init__(self, master):
     self.master = master
     self.master.geometry("365x100")
     self.master.title("VisualNovelPrototype")

     self.str1 = StringVar()
     self.str1.set("Welcome to the game")
     self.label = Label(self.master, text=self.str1.get())
     self.label.grid(row=0,column=1)

     self.button0 = Button(self.master, text="yes", command=self.start)
     self.button0.place(x=180,y=40)

     self.button1 = Button(self.master, text="no", command=self.master.destroy)
     self.button1.place(x=180,y=70)

 def label_change(self, text):
     def process():
         self.store += text[self.index]
         self.index += 1
         self.label.config(text=self.store)
         self.master.update()
         self.label_change(self.txt)
     if self.store!=text:
         time.sleep(0.100)
         process()
     else:
         pass

 def button_change(self, master, text0="", command0="", text1="", command1=""):
     self.button0.config(text=text0, command=command0)
     self.button1.config(text=text1, command=command1)

 def start(self):
     self.store=""
     self.index=0
     self.txt="Its a cold night. A storm rages outside. You hear a knock at the door."
     self.label_change(self.txt)

window=Tk()
et=gui(window)
```

When you clicked yes,this function runs which initialize self.index and self.txt for indexing the string and other one is for storing string respectively.
Then it goes to label_change function with parameter 'self.txt'.

```
 def start(self):
     self.store=""
     self.index=0
     self.txt="Its a cold night. A storm rages outside. You hear a knock at the door."
     self.label_change(self.txt)
```

The function label_change will recurse till self.store will be as same as self.txt.

```
 if self.store!=text:
     time.sleep(0.100)
     process()
 else:
     pass
```

Then it will call process function to add one character in 'self.store' variable and increment self.index by 1.At last,it will update the self.master (GUI Window).

```
def process():
     self.store += text[self.index]
     self.index += 1
     self.label.config(text=self.store)
     self.master.update()
     self.label_change(self.txt)
```

This is my first answer so if there is any problem,I am open to help.
Ciao!